# Eclipse is showing following message in the console:Unable to execute dex

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I had to delete my eclipse because of some reason.When i unzipped it from the same zip file and added the project to the workspace it is showing the problem of existence of multiple similar jar files.When i removed the multiple copy of appcompatv7 it is showing the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to right click on the Project Name, go to Build Path, Configure Build Path, Java Build Path, Order and Export tab, then uncheck your .jar library

If you have no jar library in the Order and Export tab, try to un-check Android Private Libraries.

If that doesn't work, try to remove external jars from your build path, and add them to your `libs` folder, then clean and re-build the project.

Comment: @ pez where can i find the external jar folder

Comment: @NavneetAnand Try right-clicking on your project, Properties, Android, and in the Library section remove the necessary external jars.